# Get image path from UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

i have code with dynamically generated uiimage:

```
for product in self.productObject {
                if product.code != nil{
                    self.imageView1.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: documentsDir.appendingPathComponent("myfiles").path + "/" + product.code! + ".jpg")
                }
            }
```

I need to get the path of the currently displayed image in the button:

```
@IBAction func showImagesInPopup(_ sender: Any) {
        var path = self.imageView1.image.path
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProductDetail", sender: self)
    }
```

How can I get it and save to "path"?

Comment: You could make a UIImageView subclass, add a setImage(with path: String), save it inside a "path" variable and voilà

Comment: I guess that `var path` is nil (I think that's normal behavior). What about adding an extension to `UIImageView`, with a property `imagePath`, and when you set it, it sets the image too.

Comment: I think it's a good idea